# Who stores the image in zeros and ones

Tags: image, image-processing

I wanted to know who stores the images/ videos or audios in zeros and ones. I know that an image is stored in form of zeros and ones by storing the color for each pixel in the form of zeros and ones, and similar things happen for other types of data. But my question is, for example, if I create an image using any Image creating application and store it in my computer, then what or who is storing the colors in binary form for each pixel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two types of images

- acquired from a device (camera, scanner), which measures the amount of light in the RGB channels for every pixel and converts it to a binary value; writing the values to memory is handled by the device driver.
- synthetized, from a geometric model with surface and lighting characteristics by pure computation, and every pixel value is obtained "out of nothing"; this is done by a rendering program.

After the image has been written to RAM memory, it can be transferred to disk for long term storage.